# Date Condition to get output

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, psql

I have two tables. One is where we Assign something to employee like (Job titles and Location).  The other table is Job title and Location Start date and End date.

I created a query and its working fine, but the problem is when I put the condition like assign date BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate and job title and location startdate <=  ????
job title and location enddate <=  ????

I don't know what condition I add here so when my staff uses assign date  :StartDate AND :EndDate so the output is produced. How many employees we have between assign date looking job title and location start date and end date.

Comment: Anyone ...............

Comment: Your question is little confusing. Could you please provide more details with table definition and some sample data. Then it would be easier for us to help you.